# "Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'object'" When populating a list box

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012, listbox

I'm trying to popular a list box in a Visual C# Form Application on Visual Studio 2012, however when I go to add the items to the list box, it claims the error:

**Error 1   Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'object'**

How do I write code to add in 3 objects using the + operator?

I've never used a compact SQL database before, only through web development so I am new to Visual Studio Databases, so most probably a rookie error. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**populateListBox**

```
public void populateListBox()
        {
            String query = "SELECT Bug_Code, Bug_Description, Bug_Author FROM tblBugs";
            SqlCeCommand mySqlCommand = new SqlCeCommand(query, mySqlConnection);
            try
            {
                mySqlConnection.Open();
                SqlCeDataReader mySqlDataReader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                lbxBugged.Items.Clear();
                while (mySqlDataReader.Read())
                {
                    lbxBugged.Items.Add(mySqlDataReader["Bug_Code"] + mySqlDataReader["Bug_Description"] + mySqlDataReader["Bug_Author"]);
                }
            }
            catch (SqlCeException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error populating list box");
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you want join string add mySqlDataReader["Bug_Code"].ToString() + mySqlDataReader["Bug_Description.ToString()

Comment: Thankyou Valentin, knew it would be a rookie error :)

Comment: You could do that in the SQL instead `select Bug_Code + BugDescription + Bug_Author`.  Depending on the exact DB you might need to use `||` instead of `+`

Comment: @juharr -- That's not really the best place.  Keep UI-layer stuff out of the data layer

Comment: @roryap The method is doing a DB call and populating a list box, so the data layer and UI are already mushed together

Comment: @MattMurphy -- I didn't dv but my guess would be that the error is easily searched, e.g. in google, and you didn't show any evidence that you researched it.

Comment: Ah okay, my bad. This is my first post so I will make sure I do that on the rest. I did try the conversion but not in the way that was stated.

Comment: @juharr -- Okay but that's no reason to propagate anti-patterns.  Someone in the future might come across this from a different perspective and think that it's ok to put UI stuff in a database query because a 5-figure rep user suggested it.

Comment: @roryap The thing is I don't even agree with you here.  If what you want is 3 columns concatenated together why not have the DB do it?  If this was EF I could see someone putting the concatenation in a `select` which would result in the same thing.

Comment: @juharr -- That surprises me since the resulting domain class would then not be purely-representative of the "entity".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast or convert the column's value into an actual type to make it usable, which is, in your case, strings for each of the columns.  Try this:

```
lbxBugged.Items.Add(mySqlDataReader["Bug_Code"].ToString() + 
    mySqlDataReader["Bug_Description"].ToString() + 
    mySqlDataReader["Bug_Author"].ToString());
```

Comment: Thankyou, that gets rid of the red lines! Still throwing the "Error populating list box" though. I will select your answer :) but by any chance do you have an idea as to why this is? The connection is set up and testing says it's connected, and the table column names are all matching.

Comment: That's all you're getting for an error?  It doesn't provide any more info?

Comment: Unfortunately not no, I ran it through debugging and the messagebox shows the error but nothing flags on the debug, I'm unsure on finding out what the exact error is

Comment: What if you enable break-on-exception via "Debug" > "Exceptions" check "Thrown" cb next to "Common Language Runtime Exceptions"...

Comment: You should put a breakpoint in your catch block and see what the error is.

Comment: It appears to have a problem with the line mySqlConnection.Open();, throwing the error: A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll. I will have a play around with my database as I've swapped computers so it may be an issue there.

Comment: Thankyou, didn't realise you could do that with debugging so that has helped a lot.

Comment: The debugger is a very powerful thing.  Learn to use it.  It can save you a lot of time and headaches.

Comment: Thanks to you I got it working. Turns out changing computers made it so I messed up the file path. Thankyou for your help roryap.